# Is there a way to use Nested loops for insertion in array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, nested-loops, insertion

So here is the code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a[20] = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int new_num, n, i = 0;

    for (i; i < 10; i++) {
        //printf("the elements in the array are:");
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    printf("enter the index you want to insert the element");
    scanf("%d", &n); //don't forget to add &
    printf("Enter the element");
    scanf("%d", &new_num);
    for (i = 9; i >= n; i--) {
        for (int j = 10; j > n; j--) {
            a[j] = a[i];
        }   
    }
    a[n] = new_num;

    printf("new array is:");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[and here is the output...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSSof.png)

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

I want to use a nested loop for shifting the elements to the next address, instead of using this syntax:

```
for (i = 9; i >= n; i--) {
    a[i + 1] = a[i];
}
```

but the output seems a bit eerie as I have shown in the output image.

Comment: You should add the output here, not as an external image... Just past it as code

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation points to do that

Comment: You have simple, single-loop code that works, so why are you interested in achieving the same result via more complex code?  As for your specific code, it does not make sense.  Each element that needs to be moved at all only needs to be moved once, to a specific new location.  Your code instead clobbers all of the array elements pas the insertion position with the element at the insertion position.  Inefficiently, at that.

Comment: @Antiarin, there is no reputation threshold for editing additional *text* into your question.

Comment: thank you so much. I finally understood what I did wrong, T'was so dumb of me. and as for the reputation part, I simply misunderstood what you were trying to say. I thought by just paste it as a code you meant to simply paste the image in the post, not the Output-text. xD

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this snippet:

```c
for (i=9;i>=n;i--){
    for (int j=10;j>n;j--){
        a[j]=a[i];
    }   
}
```

When `i == 4`, you're setting all elements of `a` for which the index exceeds 4 to the value of `a[4]` (which is 6). You probably want something closer to:

```c
for (int j = 10; j > n; j++) {
    a[j] = a[j - 1];
}
a[n] = new_num;
```

Also, you have a small bug in that you're assuming `a` is of length 10 but you're missing the value 3, so it only has 9 elements.

Edit: I just saw that you want to use a nested loop. Is that a hard requirement? A nested loop just isn't the right way to go here.

Comment: I got it. No, it ain't a hard requirement, was trying to something different. I was way off succeeding using a for loop . Anyways thanks, I understood the error